How to extract alphanumeric string or string using regex?
I want to extract the first instance of alphanumeric string and alpha only string. I've provided some examples below for better explanation of what I wish to achieve.
Examples:
All the examples below should output:
Expected output = Alphanumeric12 word

string1 = 123456 Alphanumeric12 word 7890 Subsequent String
string2 = Alphanumeric12 word 7890 Subsequent String
string3 = 123456 Alphanumeric12 word

The closest I got was a list of all alphanumeric and character string which is not what I wanted.
My code:
re.findall(r”(?i)\d?(?:[a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+|[a-z]+)\d?”,string)

Thanks everyone in advance!

You say the expected output for all three examples is “Alphanumeric12 word”. However, that string contains letters (of either case), numbers, and spaces - how exactly is the regex engine to know that " 7890" should not also be included in the first two examples? And why should "123456 " not be included in the final example? What distinguishes “Alphanumeric12 word” from the surrounding text in your examples? The fact that its 'words' don't start with a number?

I’m trying to see if it’s achievable using regex. And why “123456” not be included because it’s a full numeric. I’m interested in alphanumerics string and alpha only string. If that clarifies!

So, if string3 had started with 12345a , would it have been included and would the match have been "12345a Alphanumeric12 word”? And since you use re.findall do you expect to find both “Alphanumeric12 word” and "Subsequent String”, or only the first full match in the string? (in which case you don't need .findall)

Yes this would be considered too. The number can be in any position of the string

Assuming that you are looking to match substrings that are strings of words of alphanumeric characters, separated by whitespace, none of which start with a number, a simple solution would be:
import re

examples = [
    '123456 Alphanumeric12 word 7890 Subsequent String',
    'Alphanumeric12 word 7890 Subsequent String',
    '123456 Alphanumeric12 word'
]

for s in examples:
    print(re.findall('(?:[a-zA-Z]\w*\s*)+', s))

Output:
['Alphanumeric12 word ', 'Subsequent String']
['Alphanumeric12 word ', 'Subsequent String']
['Alphanumeric12 word'] 

Note that this does include whitespace following the string in the string, but that's easily gotten rid of with .strip(). If you only need the first match, you don't need to use .findall().
Also, if you don't mind a heavier regex, in favour of using .strip(), this works:
for s in examples:
    print(re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]\w*(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]\w*)*', s))


You can omit the \b here as it is implicit \s+\b[a-zA-Z]\w*

You're right, in fact that's true for both.

The first word boundary could be helpful if you want to prevent matching if there is a leading underscore or digit.

But he said the number can be in at any position in the string.

You're right @AkshayVilasPatil - but note the assumption I made at the start of the answer. That's just a minor tweak, OP accepted the answer and I think the basic solution is clear.
